# T-SQL update significantly slower than select or insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a complex query and am selecting from over 700,000 rows. The query returns a `varchar` and a `date`.

If I `select` the results this runs in under 2 minutes. If I `insert` them into a new table this takes about the same time. If I do an `update` this takes over 1 hour.

The update query is similar to the following:

```
UPDATE
    BD
SET
    datetext = V1.datetextvalue,
    datedate = V1.datevalue
FROM
    datatable AS BD
    LEFT JOIN
    aview1 AS V1
    ON BD.indexa = V1.indexa
```

The datatable is:

```
primaryKey int
indexa int
datetext varchar(max) NULL
datedate datetime NULL
```

and, other than the `primaryKey` has no indexes. `inedxa` is a unique value.

What can I do to speed this up?

**UPDATE**

The above is a gross simplification of the actual query and the supporting views. The execution plan is so complex that it is almost unreadable. The key issue for me is that the `select` is very quick, it's the update that is slow.

I have uses the query to create a temporary table - this is quick. However, if I update the main table from the temporary table this is just as slow.

Comment: Can you add the execution plan, and definition of `aview1`?

Comment: @destination-data Sorry, meant to add that to the question. The above is a gross simplification of the actual query and the supporting views. the execution plan was so complex that it was almost unreadable. The key issue for me is that the `select` is very quick, it's the update that is slow

Comment: Suspected that might be the case.  Without the table definitions, it is hard to fix the root cause of your problem.  But the answer proposed by @Vicky_Thinking might help you workaround the issue.

Comment: The select might simply use a nonclustered index with included fields to retrieve data, while the update has to modify all data pages (plus the index if needed). There's a quite a difference in scenarios like that.

Comment: Do you have any other session blocking the update? Also, which isolation level are you using?

Comment: Such a big update will definitely cause lock escalation which will probably be blocked for a long wile if there are other transactions modifying the table. Even readers can cause noticeable blocking for such big updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is keep transaction log entry to minimum so your update will be faster. Try the batch update as below.

```
 UPDATE TOP(1000) BD
 SET
    datetext = V1.datetextvalue,
    datedate = V1.datevalue
FROM datatable AS BD
    LEFT JOIN
    aview1 AS V1
    ON BD.indexa = V1.indexa
 WHILE  @@rowcount > 0
 BEGIN
     UPDATE TOP(1000) BD
 SET
    datetext = V1.datetextvalue,
    datedate = V1.datevalue
FROM datatable AS BD
    LEFT JOIN
    aview1 AS V1
    ON BD.indexa = V1.indexa
 END;
 GO
```

Comment: how does that work if you don't mind me asking?  Why will it ever stop updating in the WHILE?

Comment: I have the same question. How does the while ever stop? it will be updating the same 1000 rows over and over again. Nothing is moving it from rows 1000 and upward